# replacing octave matrix values

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, octave

I am a beginner to octave. I created a 5x5 matrix named x as follows with all ones

```
 X=ones(5,5)
```

I want to replace the all the ones in the last column(5th column) with (-3,+5) but when I give the following command it gives an error

```
 y(:,5)=(-3,+5)
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Numerical arrays cannot store other arrays as elements. You have to work with cells in order to achieve your goal:

```
X = num2cell(ones(5));
X(:,5) = {[-3 5]}

X = 
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [2,1] =  1
  [3,1] =  1
  [4,1] =  1
  [5,1] =  1
  [1,2] =  1
  [2,2] =  1
  [3,2] =  1
  [4,2] =  1
  [5,2] =  1
  [1,3] =  1
  [2,3] =  1
  [3,3] =  1
  [4,3] =  1
  [5,3] =  1
  [1,4] =  1
  [2,4] =  1
  [3,4] =  1
  [4,4] =  1
  [5,4] =  1
  [1,5] = -3 5
  [2,5] = -3 5
  [3,5] = -3 5
  [4,5] = -3 5
  [5,5] = -3 5
}
```

Alternatively, you can build that using two separate steps by concatenating the cell arrays:

```
X = [num2cell(ones(5,4)) repmat({[-3 5]},5,1)]
```

**EDIT**

Following the details in your comment:

```
X = randi([0 1],5);
idx = X(:,5) == 1; % build an indexer to the elements equal to 1 in column 5

X = num2cell(X); % convert the matrix into a cell array
X(idx,5) = {[-3 5]}; % replace the indexed elements with a vector
```

Comment: Thanx but this matrix is actually loaded using a csv file :O

Comment: You have to convert it to a cell anyway if you want to insert a vector in the last column...

Comment: Anyway, check my edit to see how to deal with a predetermined matrix.